# Value of f in A* algorithm

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence

In A* algorithm, if g=0 and h=0 then what will be the result of f?

I know f(x)=g(x)+h(x). So it is true that f(x) will be zero?

Comment: Yes. Yes! It's true. `0 + 0 = 0`. I learned this in elementary school – actually before that. Do you have any reason to believe that it's not true?

Comment: I just thought it would be a trick question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

f(x) would be 0.
But this should hardly ever occur.
g(x)=0 means you had no costs to reach x (should only be the case for the starting point)
h(x)=0 means the heuristics says that the costs to reach the goal from x costs not more than 0 (means that you are at the goal)

so f(x)=0 should only be possible if you start at the goal.